# Calculate a random position inside a 2D area excluding a subset

Tags: unity, 2d, random

Given this area

```
- - - -
- X X -
- X X -
- - - -
```

I have a **GameObject** size 4x4 and **inside another GameObject** size 2x2.

I know how to calculate a random position inside the 4x4 zone (using GameObject position and collider size), but I do not know **calculate a random position evading the 2x2 zone**.

What I am using right now is:

1. Calculate position inside 4x4.
2. If that position is inside 2x2 go back to step 1.

But it is not a good way to do this.
Do you know can I calculate a random position inside 4x4 area evading a 2x2 area?

I though generating small GameObjects, 1x1 instead if 4x4. So first select a random of the 4x4 tagged,  for examble, as "IsWalkable", and then calculate a random position insided the selected small square.

Comment: Your example suggests that your area is tile based; are you only dealing with integer coords or do you need a solution that supports decimal coords?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your objects are always rectangular, a very simple way is the following:

- split the container object into *N* sub-rectangles that are fully accessible and *M* that are fully inaccessible. In your example *N=8*, *M=1* except if the contained object is on a border (then *N=5*, *M=1*) or in a corner (*N=3*, *M=1*)
- compute the areas of each sub-rectangle:
  $$ A_i ~~ \forall i \in \{1, ..., N\}$$
- draw the random index *r* in *{1, 2, ..., N}* with probability $$p(r = i) = \frac{A_i}{\sum_{i=1}^N A_i} ~~ \forall i \in \{1, ..., N\}$$

note that the sum in the denominator is just the area of the container minus the area of the contained rectangle.

- draw a random point inside the sub-rectangle *r*.

The approach works even if the container contains other rectangles.
You can also adapt it for other shapes easily.

Here is a picture to get you started: if you can figure out the area of each of the labelled rectangle and if you can write a function that draws a point at random in a rectangle, you are done. :)

[image: illustration with 8 rectangles]

Comment: It's not too important to care for *N* if it's always going to be one contained rectangle. Then always use *N=8* and as result *3* or *5* sub-rectangles will have area zero when the contained is on a border or corner. However if you have several rectangles contained in the container, you will have to compute *N*

Comment: My maths are not the best. I need to "translate" it to my language :) I will try it. Vote up for the usefull response.